# How do I convert my WordPress website to be domain agnostic?

Tags: plugins, functions, urls, ssl, domain

If my website changes domain or protocol, the entire code base does not have to be updated. That is my desired result. More specifically, I want to add a php function to my child theme to convert all http requests to https automatically. I was given some docs to get started but I realize I have too many questions at this point. Can someone help me out?

Cheers
BJ

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you never have to use your domain in your php code for plugins / themes. There are many functions like [`get_home_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/) which automatically fetches the domain from configuration and is also protocol agnostic if you don't force a protocol via the third parameter `$scheme`.

The function `get_home_url()` internally uses [`is_ssl()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl) and the option value for `home` to decide which protocol to use.

Comment: Is <?php echo get_home_url(); ?> sufficient to make the changes I want or would I have to write more code?

Comment: In many cases `get_home_url()` or `get_permalink()` (which internally also uses `get_home_url()` via `home_url()`) will be enough as long as they yield the url you are looking for. But that depends a lot from use case to use case, so without insight to your code we can't help more thouroughly.